# That's what she said

Tags: riddle, word

Oh so very long,
Often very hard.
Endurance is the Key.

Faster, Faster,
Push harder, harder.
Euphoria at the end.

Some say that it hurts,
But not if done right.
Rush to the end, or take your time.

Keep your socks on,
Stay hydrated.
Strong to the end.

Cheering and screaming,
right at the end.
You must be tired.

Maybe a game before,
Thanks, that was fun.
Now we are done.

Comment: I think of the Against The Current song Closer, Faster(if you haven't heard it, you should have a listen :-)

Comment: Love the double entendre!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this a

> Marathon

Oh so very long,
Often very hard.
Endurance is the Key.

> marathon is long distance running race and very hard, and yes you need endurance to finish it

Faster, Faster,
Push harder, harder.
Euphoria at the end.

> Faster in running and winning one or finishing one can give you a great feeling of success

Some say that it hurts,
But not if done right.
Rush to the end, or take your time.

> running will injure you if you don't stretch or warm up. Rush or slow pace at first then rush when close to finishing.

Keep your socks on,
Stay hydrated.
Strong to the end.

> water to keep you going and socks of course are needed.

Cheering and screaming,
right at the end.
You must be tired.

> audience screams at the sidelines at also at the finish line. And you are very tired after the marathon.

Maybe a game before,
Thanks, that was fun.
Now we are done.

> running is considered a game when we are still young or for a child

Comment: Well done. Marathon was also a computer game a few years back.

Comment: actually it can be also pregnancy but not all clues will match lol

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

> It is the tiebreaker game in tennis.

The idea:

> Maybe a game before (when we were still tied), thanks that was fun; but now I lost, and there is cheering, on the other side.

Comment: It could be any game, not only tennis.

Comment: @cagirici Nope, it is only in tennis that a `game` is one of the technical terms indicating the score. Tiebreakers exist in other sports alright (volleyball, for instance), but there are only *sets* in volleyball , not *games* as in tennis.

Comment: Nice thought, but no. A tiebreaker really shouldn't hurt.

Comment: @AggieKidd It does if you lose, like I indicated in the 'idea'.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it an education?**

Oh so very long,
Often very hard.
Endurance is the Key.

> An education seems to take forever
>  and is fraught with challenges,
>  but you have to just stick with it to finish.

Faster, Faster,
Push harder, harder.
Euphoria at the end.

> The further you get, the faster the pace
>  and the greater the difficulty,
>  but when it's over: "Freeeeedom!".

Some say that it hurts,
But not if done right.
Rush to the end, or take your time.

> Forced learning is painful,
>  but not for a keen mind.
>  Graduate early or throw in a few gap years; your call.

Cheering and screaming,
right at the end.
You must be tired.

> Hooting and hollering aplenty
>  at graduation.
>  Now you can sleep in until noon every day.

Maybe a game before,
Thanks, that was fun.
Now we are done.

> I don't know about you, but I played a lot of games in gym class,
>  which was a nice way to follow art class. Thanks for the crayons, Mrs. D.
>  I need to find a job :(

Comment: Definitely a nice approach, but not it. The answer can be physically painful and cause injury if not done well.